# Defining charAt variable to use in a loop with a boolean statement for letter matching

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to create a boolean expression to tell me if a letter given is in a word using charAt. An example is if the secret word is daisy and I give the letter i, it returns true but if I give m, it returns false.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean isInSecretWord(char letter)
{
int length = secretWord.length();
char[] arr = new char[length];
for (int i=0; i<length: i++)
if (charAt[i] == letter); // this bit doesn't work
return true;
}
```

After the edits in comments this is what I have, else statement fails for some reason.

```
public boolean isInSecretWord(char letter)
{
int length = secretWord.length();
char[] arr = new char[length];
for (int i=0; i<length: i++)
if (secretWord.charAt(i) == letter); 
return true;
else return false;
}
```

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS still doesn't work, says it is an undeclared variable. which is what it said before your edit.

Comment: Ah, sry it should of course be `secretWord.charAt(i);` with round parenthesis.

Comment: What is the purpose of the array? Where’s the return statement for the negative case? Do you understand that a semicolon ends the statement so `if(condition);` has an empty statement?

Comment: @Holger It should return false if the letter is not in the secret word. I also tried adding an else statement but it threw me an error saying no if statement...

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isInSecretWord(char letter) {
    int length = secretWord.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length: i++) {
        if (secretWord.charAt(i) == letter) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You also had `if (secretWord.charAt(i) == letter);` with an empty statement for the true case. That at the same time is a strong argument for using braces `{ }`. Your `else` did not compile for that reason.

Only after the loop you know that the letter was nowhere in the secret word.

There is a short cut for finding the index of a character [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)):

```
public boolean isInSecretWord(char letter) {
    return secretWord.indexOf(letter) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I need to specify the index just yet as the next method I have to do is location based in the string to match the secret word. I am essentially building the wordle game. For example, if the secret word is "trust" and I guess the word "stuns", it would return ..*_. where the "." means the letter is in the word but in the wrong spot, "*" means the letter is in the correct spot and the "_" means the letter is not in the secret word.

Comment: I would like that game on my phone ;)